# IDE for Lua on Windows

Tags: windows, software-development, ide, lua

Recently I started learning the Lua language, but in a very limited way - Heroes of Might and Magic V map editor uses Lua for scripting custom events into the maps. But it (the map editor) use only a fraction of what Lua is and, in the end, those maps can be used only by HOMMV games and I want something different.

Are there any softwares that use Lua to build new softwares and that are not so complicated for use (as I am begining to learn the language)? I was thinking of an interface similar to that of Borland Delphi 7, only using Lua.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Mind to [edit] your question and include your requirements a bit more detailed – e.g. what features are important for you, must the software be free/open-source? For a helpful reference, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) This will increase your chances for good answers useful to you ;) Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest [ZeroBrane Studio IDE](http://studio.zerobrane.com/) (I'm the developer): it's written in Lua using wxlua/wxwidgets toolkit for GUI development and allows development and debugging of various Lua engines (Lua 5.1, 5.2, 5.3 and LuaJIT) on Windows, OSX, and Linux.

If you are looking for a way to develop GUI in Lua using something similar to Delphi, then I'm not aware of any such tool in Lua. There are several [GUI toolkits in Lua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/GraphicalUserInterfaceToolkits), but none of them generates the code from your based on your GUI design and you'll need to write the code yourself.

Comment: I meant simmilar to Delphi in a way that you can easily create simple softwares (like calculators or something like that,) as I am just beginig to learn LUA. I'll check this ZeroBraneStudio out though.